# Javascript 2 arrays of objects , get a value from one array of objects and assign it to the other array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, react-select

So i have 2 arrays of objects , i want to get the name value from one and assign it to the label and value . This is what i am doing.

```
let newAreas = [{ label: '', value: '' }];
let areas = [{name: 'Haram', condition: true, counter: 5}, {name: 'Nasr City', condition: false, counter: 3}, {name: 'Faisl', condition: true, counter: 7}];
```

i want to get the each name and assign them to label and value so now i loop

```
areas.map(area => {
      newAreas.map(val => {
        val.label = area.name;
        val.value = area.name;
  });
});

    console.log(newAreas);
```

but this only gets me the last value what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not change the existing array but returns a new one.

Comment: You want to get a new object with label equal to name and value equal to name from each of the objects in the areas array?

Comment: Could you write down your desired output ?

Comment: It's not really what role `newAreas` plays as an array with one object. Is that just there as a template for the objects you want? Nor is it clear what you need to have two keys with the same value.

Comment: Try this newAreas.push()

Comment: @Shidersz Yeah thats what i wanted

Comment: I am using react-select which needs a label and a value in my state's array in order to work properly that why i need to add them in my array ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to use `map` once, and retrieve the returned value:

```js
const areas = [
  {name: 'Haram', condition: true, counter: 5}, 
  {name: 'Nasr City', condition: false, counter: 3}, 
  {name: 'Faisl', condition: true, counter: 7}
];

const newAreas = areas.map(({name}) => ({label: name, value: name}));

console.log(newAreas);
```

This makes use of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: Thanks that did it !